# How can I transform DOCX to PDF with Microsoft Print to PDF in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, docx

I'm trying to convert DOCX to PDF with "Microsoft Print to PDF" in C#. Some objects of my document are drawings and i can't "Save As" without destructuration.

With a printing "Microsoft Print to PDF", all is fine so I want to do this action with my C# program. I've 3000 files to process.

I'm trying this code. It executes a PDF printing and create the wrong file but, it's only blank pages.

```
//path is my docx path
Application appWord = new Application();
wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(path);

PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = pdf_path;
pd.Print();
```

I'm thinking I miss something by I don't understand what.
And I don't know if the `wordDocument` can be the `streamReader` in some examples on Internet.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The drawings that you mention, that can simply be done by drawing the objects/pictures. I have a sample, i will look for it. If i find it, will share the code.

Comment: What does the code that opens the word doc have to do with the code that prints the PDF? I see no link between them - you open the word doc, then you just create some new printer document and save it. Just because you opened a word document at some point in the past doesn't mean that creating a print document will print it?

Comment: @Aousafrashid The drawings are old. They were CorelDraw object but at this time, this "Unknow Object" for the docx.

Comment: You aren't printing anything to that `PrintDocument`. You opened *Word* itself with `appWord` but then try to print in *your* application without sending any content to the printer. If you opened Word intentionally you can also print from it, with [Document.Printout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.printout?view=word-pia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your aswers.

This (simple) lines work fine :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Application appWord = new Application();
wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(path);
wordDocument.PrintOut(
    OutputFileName:pdf_path,
    PrintToFile: true
);
```

`path` is my docx source path

`pdf_path` is the destination pdf file path

I hope this topic can help someone.

Comment: For anyone else stuck, the library is
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();`

Comment: Is this code taking long time to execute? Converting one file takes lie 5 minutes.

Comment: This will print the document to PDF, its also possible to save the document to PDF, equivilent to file/save as, using: 

wordDocument.SaveAs2(FileName: pdfPath, FileFormat:Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);

The advantage of save vs print is that the items listed in the  table of contents can be used as hyperlinks to the respective sections of the document. That feature is missing from the printed version.